# Hide assembly and does not occupy the position

Tags: ios, swift

[image]

click  'hide label3'
code:label3.hidden = true

[image]

I want label2 and label4 connected together
Could only be modified  label4’s  frame？
code:label4.frame.origin.y = label4.frame.origin.y - label3.frame.size.height

I don't want this way to solve this problem
If there are many labels below label3 
I will crazy

Comment: can you edit your question to show your code, Fasoal?

Comment: Use Autolayout, set the height constraint of label which is hidden to zero.

Comment: Use Autolayout, set the height constraint of label which is hidden to zero.        this is not used

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use Horizontal Stack View  ,   hiden one label  others  connected together